# How to load balance without an external load balancing router?

Tags: load-balancing, linux

I want to load balance HTTPS requests across several Linux servers. The application requires session affinity, so once a user gets connected the same server needs to handle all subsequent requests from that user.  Is there a reliable way to do this without deploying an external load balancing router or adding any additional hardware?  The application will be deployed to a number of clients, some of whom are reluctant to buy more hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used mod_proxy_balancer: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html

It has the stickyness you need and is a software only solution.

Comment: The redundancy part is very untrue. You can setup Heartbeat or similar software that will give you redundancy.

Comment: @Antoine - fair point. I have removed that warning.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware load balancers provide better performance but you have the option of running a software-only load balancer. There are plenty of [open source options](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/load-balancer-open-source-software.html) available.

Answer (score 0):

An oldie but a goodie is Resonate CentralDispatch, which does a lot of neat things and can be deployed on your servers or on separate servers.  Used it for years before switching to BigIPs.  It isn't free though.